# Получить ID созданного потока

Tags: c#

Есть список функций:

```cs
IReadOnlyCollection<Action<object>> actions;
```

Далее каждая функция запускается в потоке:

```cs
foreach (var act in actions)
{               
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(act));
}
```

Возможно ли в данном случае получить ID созданного потока? Если да, то как именно? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` ?

Comment: Отправка чего либо в пул потоков не гарантирует, что поток будет создаваться каждый раз.

Comment: @tym32167, ``Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`` только сам поток получит свой ID. Так через пул потоков возможно получит ID потока, т.е. извне?

Comment: зачем кому то знать илентификаторы потоков из пула потоков? Тогда уже создавайте потоки руками, если они вам для какой то причины нужны.